# How to uninstall ASM bytecode viewer from my Mac?

Tags: android, kotlin, bytecode

I installed 2 plugins, 1 is ASM bytecode viewer, the other is ASM bytecode viewer for kotlin, then my Android studio can't start... I checked the low of AS and realized that there is a duplicated installed, may I ask how should I get my AS back by removing unecessary ASM bytecode viewer?

```
2022-12-04 19:36:47,567 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,595 [     28]   INFO - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - loading shell env: /bin/bash -l -i -c '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/var/folders/23/fhstgrf11p523zqv5b4z1zqw0000gn/T/intellij-shell-env.11475173051245961351.tmp' 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,612 [     45]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034, 21 Nov 2021 13:35) 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,614 [     47]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Mac OS X (12.6, x86_64) 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,626 [     59]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 (JetBrains s.r.o.) 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,626 [     59]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,630 [     63]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Didea.vendor.name=Google -XX:ErrorFile=/Users/savypan/java_error_in_studio_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/Users/savypan/java_error_in_studio.hprof -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2020.3 -Didea.executable=studio -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Didea.home.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,631 [     64]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: /Users/savypan/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,631 [     64]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/lib 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,671 [    104]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_CN JNU=UTF-8 file.encoding=UTF-8
  idea.config.path=/Users/savypan/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3
  idea.system.path=/Users/savypan/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3
  idea.plugins.path=/Users/savypan/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins
  idea.log.path=/Users/savypan/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3 
2022-12-04 19:36:47,749 [    182]   WARN - .intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil - can't get shell environment 
java.lang.RuntimeException: command [/bin/bash, -l, -i, -c, '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/printenv.py' '/var/folders/23/fhstgrf11p523zqv5b4z1zqw0000gn/T/intellij-shell-env.11475173051245961351.tmp']
    exit code:127 text:0 out:bash: no job control in this shell
env: python: No such file or directory
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil$ShellEnvReader.runProcessAndReadOutputAndEnvs(EnvironmentUtil.java:353)
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil$ShellEnvReader.readShellEnv(EnvironmentUtil.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil$ShellEnvReader.readShellEnv(EnvironmentUtil.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil.getShellEnv(EnvironmentUtil.java:204)
    at com.intellij.util.EnvironmentUtil.lambda$loadEnvironment$0(EnvironmentUtil.java:106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022-12-04 19:36:48,001 [    434]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 328 ms 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,249 [    682]   INFO - ntellij.idea.ApplicationLoader - CPU cores: 8; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2aabd8bc[Running, parallelism = 7, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@2f5b9028 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,348 [    781]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, path=/Users/savypan/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins/Kotlin, version=203-1.6.10-release-923-AS7717.8) misses optional descriptor kotlin-nodejs.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,350 [    783]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, path=/Users/savypan/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins/Kotlin, version=203-1.6.10-release-923-AS7717.8) misses optional descriptor native-debug.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,351 [    784]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, path=/Users/savypan/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins/Kotlin, version=203-1.6.10-release-923-AS7717.8) misses optional descriptor js-debug.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,494 [    927]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy, version=203.7717.56.2031.7935034) misses optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,495 [    928]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Groovy, id=org.intellij.groovy, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy, version=203.7717.56.2031.7935034) misses optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,580 [   1013]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Java, id=com.intellij.java, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/java, version=203.7717.56.2031.7935034) misses optional descriptor profiler-java.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,582 [   1015]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Java, id=com.intellij.java, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/java, version=203.7717.56.2031.7935034) misses optional descriptor java-features-trainer.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,613 [   1046]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin, version=203-1.5.20-release-289-AS7717.8) misses optional descriptor kotlin-nodejs.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,618 [   1051]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin, version=203-1.5.20-release-289-AS7717.8) misses optional descriptor native-debug.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,619 [   1052]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Kotlin, id=org.jetbrains.kotlin, path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin, version=203-1.5.20-release-289-AS7717.8) misses optional descriptor js-debug.xml 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,672 [   1105]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Problems found loading plugins:
  The ASM Bytecode Outline (id=ASM Bytecode Outline, path=~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins/ASM-BO, version=0.3.5) plugin Plugin 'ASM Bytecode Outline' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,728 [   1161]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: IDEA CORE (203.7717.56), Layoutlib (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Layoutlib Legacy (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Google Login (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), CIDR Base (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), C/C++ Language Support (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Clangd support (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), com.intellij.platform.images (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), JetBrains maven model api classes (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), JetBrains Repository Search (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Subversion (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Smali Support (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Machine Learning Code Completion (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Configuration Script (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Copyright (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Java (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), JUnit (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Java IDE Customization (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Java Stream Debugger (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Java Bytecode Decompiler (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Properties (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Gradle (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Java Internationalization (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Resource Bundle Editor (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Task Management (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Mercurial (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), WebP Support (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), EditorConfig (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Terminal (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Git (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), ChangeReminder (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), GitHub (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Next File Prediction (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Shell Script (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), TextMate Bundles (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), YAML (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Settings Repository (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), IntelliLang (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), TestNG (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Code Coverage for Java (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Groovy (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Gradle-Java (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Google Cloud Tools Core (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Android (2020.3.1 Patch 4), Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Firebase Testing (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Compose (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Android NDK Support (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Android APK Support (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Google Developers Samples (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Test Recorder (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), App Links Assistant (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Firebase App Indexing (203.7717.56.2031.7935034) 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,728 [   1161]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: ASM Bytecode Viewer (7.2), ASM Bytecode Viewer Support Kotlin (1.1), Dart (203.8452), Kotlin (203-1.6.10-release-923-AS7717.8), Flutter (65.2.1), Markdown (203.6682.134) 
2022-12-04 19:36:48,728 [   1161]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Disabled plugins: Firebase Services (203.7717.56.2031.7935034), Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (0.3.0(203-1.6.0-release-795-IJ)-54) 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,307 [   1740]   INFO - m.intellij.util.io.StorageLock - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=1260 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,315 [   1748]   INFO - tellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil - uninterruptible FileChannels will be used for indexes 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,361 [   1794]   INFO - m.intellij.ui.mac.touchbar.NST - touchbar-server isn't running, skip nst loading 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,418 [   1851]   INFO - tellij.util.io.storage.Storage - Space waste in /Users/savypan/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/caches/attrib.dat is 26155394 bytes. Compacting now. 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,420 [   1853]   INFO - tellij.util.io.storage.Storage - Compact failed: /Users/savypan/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/caches/attrib.dat.storageData.backup 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,420 [   1853]   INFO - tellij.util.io.storage.Storage - Done compacting in 2msec. 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,441 [   1874]   INFO - cation.options.RegistryManager - Registry values changed by user: external.system.auto.import.disabled = true 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,464 [   1897]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,492 [   1925]   INFO - intellij.diagnostic.JitWatcher - JIT compilation state checking enabled 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,615 [   2048]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2022-12-04 19:36:49,638 [   2071]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2022-12-04 19:36:50,655 [   3088]   INFO - leBasedIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done: 1055 
2022-12-04 19:36:50,748 [   3181]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done: 92 
2022-12-04 19:36:52,552 [   4985]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2022-12-04 19:36:52,553 [   4986]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator) 
2022-12-04 19:36:52,587 [   5020]   INFO - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - Registry value 'external.system.auto.import.disabled' has changed to 'true' 
2022-12-04 19:36:52,622 [   5055]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier 
2022-12-04 19:36:52,625 [   5058]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,592 [   7025]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Xcode" not found [Plugin: com.intellij] 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,602 [   7035]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "Xcode" not found [Plugin: com.intellij.cidr.base] 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,805 [   7238]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - action with the ID "showBytecodeViewer" was already registered. Action being registered is ASM Bytecode Viewer (Shows the bytecode viewer and ASMified code from the current class); Registered action is ASM Bytecode Viewer (Shows the bytecode viewer and ASMified code from the current class) Plugin: ASM Bytecode Viewer Support Kotlin [Plugin: ASM Bytecode Viewer Support Kotlin] 
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: action with the ID "showBytecodeViewer" was already registered. Action being registered is ASM Bytecode Viewer (Shows the bytecode viewer and ASMified code from the current class); Registered action is ASM Bytecode Viewer (Shows the bytecode viewer and ASMified code from the current class) Plugin: ASM Bytecode Viewer Support Kotlin [Plugin: ASM Bytecode Viewer Support Kotlin]
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.reportActionError(ActionManagerImpl.java:387)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerChameleon(ActionManagerImpl.java:1325)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.addToMap(ActionManagerImpl.java:1298)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:1268)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerOrReplaceActionInner(ActionManagerImpl.java:753)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.processActionElement(ActionManagerImpl.java:726)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerPluginActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:535)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.registerActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:47)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:733)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:49)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.access$createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:13)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter$doCreateInstance$1.run(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:218)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:42)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:457)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:440)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager.getInstance(ActionManager.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader.preload(ActionPreloader.java:15)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$preload$0(Preloader.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader.lambda$preload$1(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022-12-04 19:36:54,807 [   7240]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4  Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,810 [   7243]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,810 [   7243]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,811 [   7244]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Plugin to blame: ASM Bytecode Viewer Support Kotlin version: 1.1 
2022-12-04 19:36:54,812 [   7245]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Last Action:  
2022-12-04 19:36:54,998 [   7431]   INFO - verflags.ServerFlagInitializer - Enabled server flags: analytics/surveys/followup, exceptions/ClassCastException 
2022-12-04 19:36:55,688 [   8121]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - Key org.objectweb.asm.idea.plugin.view.BytecodeOutline duplicated 
org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException: Key org.objectweb.asm.idea.plugin.view.BytecodeOutline duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:119)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:364)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectLoadHelper.registerComponents(projectLoader.kt:25)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:242)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.access$prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$openProject$$inlined$runInAutoSaveDisabledMode$lambda$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$openProject$$inlined$runInAutoSaveDisabledMode$lambda$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$progressTask$1.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022-12-04 19:36:55,689 [   8122]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4  Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034 
2022-12-04 19:36:55,689 [   8122]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-12-04 19:36:55,689 [   8122]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - OS: Mac OS X 
2022-12-04 19:36:55,689 [   8122]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - Last Action:  
2022-12-04 19:36:56,476 [   8909]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - Key org.objectweb.asm.idea.plugin.view.BytecodeOutline duplicated 
org.picocontainer.PicoRegistrationException: Key org.objectweb.asm.idea.plugin.view.BytecodeOutline duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:119)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerServices(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:364)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.registerComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectLoadHelper.registerComponents(projectLoader.kt:25)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:242)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.access$prepareProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$openProject$$inlined$runInAutoSaveDisabledMode$lambda$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl$openProject$$inlined$runInAutoSaveDisabledMode$lambda$1.invoke(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator$run$progressTask$1.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:658)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022-12-04 19:36:56,477 [   8910]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4  Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034 
2022-12-04 19:36:56,477 [   8910]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-12-04 19:36:56,477 [   8910]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - OS: Mac OS X 
2022-12-04 19:36:56,477 [   8910]  ERROR - ect.impl.ProjectFrameAllocator - Last Action:  
2022-12-04 19:36:56,482 [   8915]   INFO - gs.impl.UpdateCheckerComponent - channel: release
```

Anyone who experienced the similar issue can tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I resolved by finding the real path of AS then deleted the libs.